Can I submit an additional document after submitting the documents via self upload in TLS contact (UK visa)?
I submitted my documents via self upload in TLS contact for my UK visitor visa application. However, I just received a letter confirming my registration to the event I am attending in UK by its organizers. Previously, I only submitted a document I received (that looks like an invoice) when I registered for this conference online.
I have not yet gone to the TLS centre to give my biometric data. Can I ask the TSL assistant to upload this document when I am there? Is it possible to do it as I have already submitted via the self upload?
Extra point: My university has written a sponsor letter for my trip, and there they have mentioned that I am going for this event.
Please let me know me if someone knows about this. Thank you so much for the help in advance.

What did TLS say when you contacted them to ask about this?

There is sadly no way to contact them regarding any questions. No contactable e-mail or phone.

Look for "price list" or "added value services". For just 50 EUR or so they will probably let you scan additional documents.

Update: When I was at the TSL for my biodata submission, I asked if I can submit these additional documents and it could. So they uploaded these additional documents on the spot for a fee of 50 euros. I received the visa without any issue.
